# Chrome: Is there a way to move plugin buttons to a row/toolbar under navigation bar?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to move plugin buttons to a row/toolbar under navigation bar?

At the moment I have install ten plugins or so and they are taking a lot of space and as a result I cannot shrink the browser size beyond a certain threshold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can hide the icons by right-clicking them:

   [image]
2. You can resize the address bar to be bigger and the extensions bar to be smaller:

   [image]
   [image]

Do any of these solutions help?

Comment: I already knew I can hide them, and even though resizing the address bar is not exactly what I was looking for, it is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I too find this helpful. Additionally, I too would like a means to the move the icons to row underneath the navigation bar / address text field (as originally requested) -- in order to both have a wide address text field and see all the extension icons at once. Is there still no means to do this?